# Git checkout branch but file changed

Tags: git

I'm working on [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/). I git clone its source code. When I `git status`, everything works well.

```
FFmpeg git:(master) git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But now I want to change branch to `release/3.4`, some files have been changed.

```
FFmpeg git:(master) git checkout release/3.4
Switched to branch 'release/3.4'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/release/3.4'.
FFmpeg git:(release/3.4) ✗ git status
On branch release/3.4
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/release/3.4'.
Untracked files:
        (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

libavcodec/codec_list.c
libavcodec/parser_list.c
libavdevice/indev_list.c
libavdevice/outdev_list.c
libavfilter/filter_list.c
libavformat/demuxer_list.c
libavformat/muxer_list.c

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I'm very confused. I have never changed these files.

Comment: you should check whether those files existed on your original branch..

Comment: Yes they are on master branch.

Comment: perhaps you will need a 'hard' checkout where untracked files are removed.. ps. i never used git directly since i'm prone to mess the entire repo..

Comment: I do not know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In master those files [are](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/.gitignore) in `.gitignore`, but in `release/3.4` they [are not](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/3.4/libavcodec/.gitignore). Maybe they are not used in that release, or `.gitignore` in the release branch is wrong. In general it is better to clean build artifacts before switching the branch, to prevent unexpected behavior from VCS or subsequent build.